# Excel Index Match Date range and return SUM of matches

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have dug around the existing posts but can't find my specific issue so wanted to ask the question. I have a basic spreadsheet at the moment for keeping track of financial information like daily expenses, i want to do more graphs and a summary of spends for weeks and months but have issues with what i am trying to achieve. In essence i want to match the information that includes a month i want to match, for example "/11/2016" and return the SUM of all these matches in another cell (I4 in my example). So far i have this but know i am doing something wrong. The cells are set to DD/MM/YYYY format but i always get the #N/A error.

Any help would be appreciated. Sample is in A3:D5 below:

Date    Amount  Payment From    Payment Method
28/11/2016  24,000  Car sale money less 1000 deposit paid   CASH
22/11/2016  1,000   Deposit for car purchase    CASH

My code at present in I4 is:
=INDEX($B$4:$B$6,MATCH("/11/2016",$A$4:$A$6,0))

I realize i am missing the SUM part and as you can tell i am a novice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Greetings from Hong Kong

Comment: WELCOME! Your example is not very clear. From what I understand, you should look at the formula for MONTH, SUMIF and YEAR. add a screenshot or google sheet so that we can understand better.

Comment: Apologies, I expected the format would be corrected when pasted. I think I have the answer from the other user but if not I will fix my post with a screenshot.

Comment: The other user is also me, unless you have another post somewhere else :P ;)

Comment: hey again. sorry i missed that it was you also :) just tried your solution and its perfect, thanks so much. allows me to continue the budget and graphing. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be careful with how the date is entered in the cell. It should be entered in the format MM/DD/YYYY. However you can set the display format to be DD-MM-YYYY.

You can use this formula to calculate the sum of all amount in month 11 and year 2016

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A4:A5)=11)*--(YEAR(A4:A5)=2016)*B4:B5)
```

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAPI5WWFtapd9-IYK4AkgBQsnuyzfjjzo42sz94n4ck/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment and a answer, I will try the solution when I get home.  You are kind.